# How to search between two Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search, controller

I have View page rendered with two outside pages included (@{Html.RenderAction) in One.
  All 3 pages have one controller. By default i take all data from MSSQL Database and i have result. Now i need to Filter results by Date, and to take results between some dates.

Here is HTML Code of Search form:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Reporti", "Reporti", null, FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Od Datum:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="datumOD" name="datumOD" class="datumOD"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Do Datum:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="max" name="datumDO" class="datumDO"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Baraj" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

> Url of page is:h**p://localhost:41777/Reporti/Reporti

After click Search Button i have this URL

> h**p://localhost:41777/Reporti/Reporti?datumOD=01.03.2017&datumDO=02.03.2017

Here is code of controller

```
public ActionResult Reporti(string filter, DateTime? datumOD, DateTime? datumDO)
    {
        Session["invoiceFrom"] = datumOD;
        Session["invoiceTo"] = datumDO;


        return View(); 
    }
    public ActionResult reportIZ(DateTime? datumOD, DateTime? datumDO)
    {
        var smetkis = db.smetkis.Include(s => s.firmi);
        return View(smetkis.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Report(DateTime? datumOD, DateTime? datumDO)
    {
        var ponudis = db.ponudis.Include(s => s.ponudaDets).Where(x => x.odobreno);
        return View(ponudis.ToList());
    }
```

My question is, how to implement code in *public ActionResult Reporti* to filter result between dates.

Comment: A wild guess, based on the sparse info you have given: `var filteredResult = db.Whatever.Where(x => x.datumOD >= datumOD && x.datumDO <= datumDO).ToList()`

Comment: is it possible to filter from two tables, ex. ponudis, and smetkis in one together ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition:

```
public ActionResult Reporti(DateTime? datumOD, DateTime? datumDO)
{
    var ponudis = db.ponudis.Include(s => s.ponudaDets).AsQueryable();
    if(datumOD.HasValue) //If we have date - add condition
       ponudis = ponudis.Where(x => x.odobreno >= datumOD);
    if(datumDO.HasValue) //If we have date - add condition
       ponudis = ponudis.Where(x => x.odobreno <= datumDO);
    return View(ponudis.ToList());
}
```

If you need to get data from 2 tables at once you should use `Union`. But if your tables have different structure you should create separate class like `RowViewModel`. like this:

```
public class RowViewModel
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int DateTime? Odobreno {get; set;}
   //your other properties
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Reporti(DateTime? datumOD, DateTime? datumDO)
{
    var ponudis = db.ponudis.Include(s => s.ponudaDets).AsQueryable();
    var smetkis = db.smetkis.Include(s => s.firmi).AsQueryable();
    if(datumOD.HasValue) //If we have date - add condition
    {
       smetkis = smetkis.Where(x => x.odobreno >= datumOD);
       ponudis = ponudis.Where(x => x.odobreno >= datumOD);
    }

    if(datumDO.HasValue) //If we have date - add condition
    {
       smetkis = smetkis.Where(x => x.odobreno >= datumOD);
       ponudis = ponudis.Where(x => x.odobreno <= datumDO);
    }

    var res = smetkis.Select(x => new RowViewModel 
    { 
       Id = x.ID, 
       Odobreno = x.odobreno
       //other properties if you need        
    }).Union(ponudis.Select(x => new RowViewModel //note Union 
    { 
       Id = x.ID, 
       Odobreno = x.odobreno
       //other properties if you need        
    }));
    return View(res);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but problem for me is that i need together in One place to do this for ponudis = > ToList also in the same time to take data from smetkis => ToList in same time, Is this possible to do in public ActionResult Reporti in sametime ?